# How can I use autofac container.Resolve<> in the orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I know autofac the best practice use constructor injection whenever possible and orchard did. use global container is not a good idea, but I just want to know is there a way to use container.Resolve<> in the orchard or how to get the component in the orchard?

Yes I know in the orchard we can use IDependency, but when in the webservice, in the view etc...how can I get component like container.Resolve where I can get the container.

Comment: Your question might be a little clearer if you posted some example code with comments to show what you mean.

Comment: Seems to me like you would want to use Container.Resolve in your repository, or maybe in your controller, and then push out a view or some JSON from there.  But without some code to act as a reference, it's going to be hard to have a conversation about it.  Have you studied the Orchard source and examples to see how they do it?

Comment: Hi Robert
I checked the orchard source code
in the controller I can easy get the blogService like code below constructor injection
public BlogController(IOrchardServices services, IBlogService blogService...
but in the asp.net mvc view can I get blogService

Comment: Orchard use the code var container = builder.Build(); in the OrchardStarter but didnot share the container so how can I use the container.Resolve

Comment: The BlogController should be *returning a View.*  It should go something like this: Model ==> controller ==> view or blogservice ==> controller ==> view, something like that

Comment: Hi Robert, sorry not ask clear, I just want to call resolve in the orchard view, right now I got the answer, I can use Html.Resolve<IAuthenticationService>() in the view which referenced WorkContext

Comment: @ethan is this method an extension method? if yes, which library you have included to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

In the view, you have a `WorkContext` that has a `Resolve` method.

```
var contentDefinitionManager = WorkContext.Resolve<IContentDefinitionManager>();
```

I had a similar issue, where I needed to check a permission in my User part override cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://orchardproject.net/docs/Developer-FAQ.ashx#How_to_build_a_WCF_service_that_exposes_Orchard_functionality_14

Comment: Hi Guy, thks, I think I got the answer after check the orchard source code I can use the code Html.Resolve<IAuthenticationService>().GetAuthenticatedUser() in the view.